# UITable view inside custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to put a uitableview inside custom view but the table view take the whole view and seems it take zeros for all sides constraints even I gave it constraints from interface builder. and also the custom cell nib doesn't appear!

here's my custom view class code:

```
import UIKit
 class Example: UIView {
     @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
     @IBOutlet weak var bitTableList: UITableView!
     override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
        
    }
     override init(frame: CGRect) {
         
         super.init(frame: frame)
     }
     
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          commonInit()
        }
     
     func commonInit() {
          Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContentPlayingLeftView", owner: self, options: nil)
          self.contentView.fixInView(self)
          bitTableList.register(PlayingNowTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PLAYINGNOWCELL")
          bitTableList.delegate = self
          bitTableList.dataSource = self
         
        }
}

extension Example: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
        
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: PlayingNowTableViewCell = self.bitTableList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PLAYINGNOWCELL") as! PlayingNowTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

can any body help me with this issue?

here's mu suitable view with it's constraint

[image: constraint from interfacebuilder]

and here's the result I got

[image: result I got]

and finally the table view cell class

and finally here's my suitable view cell class

```
import UIKit

class PlayingNowTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you share an image of your set up with the constraints in Interface Builder.

Comment: Also maybe share some code of PlayingNowTableViewCell along with an image of what you see - all of this could help one of us debug.

Comment: I did it could you check please

Comment: Have you set the class of the UITableViewCell in the storyboard / xib file to PlayingNowTableViewCell ?

Comment: yeah I did that

Comment: To be honest, the issue is not completely clear. Is there an issue with the custom UI of the cell not showing or the issue is with autolayout ? If possible put your set up on a github repo and maybe someone will help you.

Comment: the issue in that my suitable view take the whole view sides and make every thing in it disappear, and also the custom nib cell doesn't appear in it.

Comment: Maybe upload this on github so someone can run your code and have a look at what is wrong.

Comment: I solved this problem.
i add tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell") into UIView's init.

So you should use it instead of bitTableList.register(PlayingNowTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PLAYINGNOWCELL").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I onderstand well, you can make it programmatically. In your controller class declare containerView and tableView and set constraints:

```
class Aiuto: UIViewController {

let tableView = UITableView()
let cellId = "cellId" //cell identifier

let containerTableView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .red
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return v
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId) // register your custom cell
    tableView.backgroundColor = .orange
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(containerTableView)
    containerTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    containerTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    containerTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    containerTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    
    containerTableView.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.fillSuperview(padding: .init(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20))
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerTableView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerTableView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerTableView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerTableView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    
 }
}
```

After that create the exstension fo tableView Delegate and DataSource:

```
extension Aiuto: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell //declare your custom cell
    cell.exampleLabel.text = "This is index path: \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    50
 }
}
```

And now add your custom cell (I put in a simple label)

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

let exampleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    
    contentView.addSubview(exampleLabel)
    exampleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    exampleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    exampleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    exampleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

And this is the result: Gray space is controller background, the Red space is container of table view and Orange is the table view

[image]

Comment: my table view not in uivew controller it's in a UIView with custom class